# Crystal Reports Pie Chart Percentage Doesn't Sum Up to 100%

Tags: rounding, pie-chart, crystal-reports-2013

we created a Crystal Report which includes pie charts. But the percentages don't add up to 100%. We discovered that it might be a rounding error. We used the diagram assistant to create the chart.

See the attached screenshots for clarification.

Any idea how to get 100%?

Thanks a lot in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGhRA.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaKnm.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding to 100% for pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823106/rounding-to-100-for-pie-chart)

Comment: It's not a duplicate to that post. This one is about SAP Crystal Reports. But one answer in that thread gives some insight: "This is a very common problem in statistical reporting and there is no real good way of handling it." so it helped me a bit. The problem is "solved" for now because there is new data in the dataset that this report handles and it sums up to 100%. But I still think this is a problem thats needs to be addressed. Thanks for the link.