# How to calculate 100% percentage in java after us Math.round() to display type int?

Tags: java

I have 1 list of double values that sums to 100 %. This list contains these values:

```
[13.253 , 12.0482, 30.1205 ,13.253 , 31.3253 ]
```

I want to display the int values in view. So I use `Math.round(item)` on all items of List. After that the list contains:

```
[13 , 12, 30 ,13 , 31 ]
```

When I sum the list its int value is 99% . How to fix it? Do I have to Math.round all items. Item last of list = 100 - count all % item other it. It will make code handle so much

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use 2 lists: 1st list to keep "real" list with double values to be used in the program, and the 2nd to the view purpose, with Math.round() executed.

Comment: This Q was already marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes that's odd - the OP answered 3 minutes after the dupe close, and this is hardly a long answer.

Comment: I checked and answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483430/how-to-make-rounded-percentages-add-up-to-100 .