# Total Percentage Not Adding up to 100 (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage

Need your feedback please. I am struggling with the following code to make percentage equal to 100.

```
SELECT animaltype, size, SUM(total) AS total,
ROUND(( SUM(total) * 100 / SUM( SUM(total)) OVER ()),2) AS percentage
FROM animals
WHERE sponsored_animalid IS NULL
GROUP BY animaltype, size
ORDER BY animaltype, size DESC;
```

This is the output, which equates to 99.99% hence making the query incorrect. [image: Result Table]

I need the percentage column to be rounded upto 2 decimal places, but total needs to add up to 100. I dont know what is the bug?

As soon as I edit ROUND( ...,3) - the code adds up to 100. But I need the figures to be rounded up to 2 decimal places strictly.

Here is the output when I round up to 3 decimal places and total is 100: [image: Roundup 3 places]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/13483430/42346 for discussion of options to address this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I looked this one up but I need some elaboration on how to implement Largest Remainder Method in this context.

Comment: You "dont know what is the bug".  There **is no bug**. It is a fallacy to expect imprecise values (rounding is by definition imprecise) with any arbitrary precision to sum to a precise value .  What happens if you round the same date to  4 places instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is syntactically incorrect, but I get what you mean.

That's not a perfect solution, but perhaps you can reduce the average rounding error by using a rounding function that round to the nearest even number rather than away from zero:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myround(numeric, integer) RETURNS numeric
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT CASE WHEN abs($1 * 10::numeric ^ $2 % 1) = 0.5
            THEN round($1 * 10::numeric ^ $2 / 2, 0)
                 * 2 / 10::numeric ^ $2
            ELSE round($1, $2)
       END';
```

For a really perfect solution you would have to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13483430/42346).

Answer (score 0):

Possible practical solution to your issue is **rounding the final aggregate by one decimal place less than the rounding on the previous more granular level**

```
INSERT INTO animals (animaltype, size, total)
VALUES 
('Bird', 'Small', 1615),('Bird', 'Medium', 3130),('Bird', 'Large', 8120),
('Cat', 'Small', 518015),('Cat', 'Medium', 250575),('Cat', 'Large', 439490),
('Dog', 'Small', 336680),('Dog', 'Medium', 942095),('Dog', 'Large', 978115);
        
SELECT
animaltype, 
size,
total,
percentage_exact,
percentage_rd2,
sum(percentage_exact) over ()  as all_perc_exact_sum,
sum(percentage_rd2) over ()  as   all_perc_rd2_sum,
round(sum(percentage_rd2) over ()  ,1) as all_perc_rd2_sum_rd1
FROM
  (
  SELECT  
  animaltype, 
  size,
  total,
  100.0 * total / (SUM(total) over ()) as percentage_exact,  
  round(100.0 * total / (SUM(total) over ()),2)  as percentage_rd2
  FROM animals       
  ) s


| animaltype |   size |  total |     percentage_exact | percentage_rd2 | all_perc_exact_sum | all_perc_rd2_sum | all_perc_rd2_sum_rd1 |
|------------|--------|--------|----------------------|----------------|--------------------|------------------|----------------------|
|       Bird |  Small |   1615 | 0.046436935622305255 |           0.05 |                100 |            99.99 |                  100 |
|       Bird | Medium |   3130 |  0.08999851919369378 |           0.09 |                100 |            99.99 |                  100 |
|       Bird |  Large |   8120 |  0.23347858653443881 |           0.23 |                100 |            99.99 |                  100 |
|        Cat |  Small | 518015 |    14.89475492655632 |          14.89 |                100 |            99.99 |                  100 |
|        Cat | Medium | 250575 |    7.204913401584607 |            7.2 |                100 |            99.99 |                  100 |
|        Cat |  Large | 439490 |   12.636884728573955 |          12.64 |                100 |            99.99 |                  100 |
|        Dog |  Small | 336680 |     9.68073528502646 |           9.68 |                100 |            99.99 |                  100 |
|        Dog | Medium | 942095 |   27.088547904084006 |          27.09 |                100 |            99.99 |                  100 |
|        Dog |  Large | 978115 |   28.124249712824213 |          28.12 |                100 |            99.99 |                  100 |
```

So here round  first by 2 decimal place

```
round(100.0 * total / (SUM(total) over ()),2)  as percentage_rd2
```

and then round the aggregate by 1 decimal place

```
round(sum(percentage_2) over ()  ,1) as   all_perc_rd2_sum_rd1
```