# Rounded percentages that add up to 100% in group_by statement

Tags: r, group-by, format, label, rounding

I'm having a hard time making rounded percentages that add up to 100% within groups.

Consider the following example:

```r
# Loading main library used
library(dplyr)

# Creating the basic data frame
df = data.frame(group = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'),
                categories = c('Cat1','Cat2','Cat3','Cat4','Cat1','Cat2','Cat3','Cat4'),
                values = c(2200,4700,3000,2000,2900,4400,2200,1000))

print(df)
#   group categories values
# 1     A       Cat1   2200
# 2     A       Cat2   4700
# 3     A       Cat3   3000
# 4     A       Cat4   2000
# 5     B       Cat1   2900
# 6     B       Cat2   4400
# 7     B       Cat3   2200
# 8     B       Cat4   1000

df_with_shares = df %>%
  # Calculating group totals and adding them back to the main df
  left_join(df %>% 
              group_by(group) %>% 
              summarize(group_total = sum(values)),
            by='group') %>%
  # Calculating each category's share within the groups
  mutate(group_share = values / group_total,
         group_share_rounded = round(group_share,2))


# Summing the rounded shares within groups
rounded_totals = df_with_shares %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(total_share = sum(group_share_rounded))


print(rounded_totals)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# group total_share
# <chr>       <int>
#   1 A        0.99
#   2 B        1.01
# Note how the totals do not add up to 100% as expected
```

I am aware of a few generic solutions to the "rounding percentages to add up to 100%" problem, as explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483430/how-to-make-rounded-percentages-add-up-to-100/13483486#13483486). I was even able to make a little R implementation of one of those approaches, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73832599/making-data-labels-with-rounded-percentages-that-add-up-to-100-in-r). This is what it would look like if I just applied that R approach to this problem:

```r
df_with_rounded_shares = df %>% 
  mutate(
    percs = values / sum(values),
    percs_cumsum = cumsum(percs),
    percs_cumsum_round = round(percs_cumsum, 2),
    percs_cumsum_round_offset = replace_na(lag(percs_cumsum_round,1),0),
    percs_rounded_final = percs_cumsum_round - percs_cumsum_round_offset)
```

However, the method I devised in the thread above does not work as I would like. It just calculates the shares of the `values` column across the **whole** dataset. In other words, it does not take into consideration the **grouping** variable representing the multiple groups in the data, **each** of which need their rounded values to add up to 100% independently from every other group.

What can I do to generate a column of rounded percentages that add up to 100% by group?

PS: While writing this question I actually found something that worked, so I'll answer my own question below. I know it's super simple, but I think it's still worth having a direct answer here on SO addressing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method devised in your implementation (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73832599/making-data-labels-with-rounded-percentages-that-add-up-to-100-in-r)) just needs a few small tweaks to make it work.

First, include a `group_by` statement before calculating the new columns. Also, you need to use a `reframe` statement instead of the `mutate` statement you have now.

In essence, this is what it'll look like:

```r
# Modified version of your implementation of the rounding procedure. 
# The new procedure below accommodates for grouping variables.
df_with_rounded_shares_by_group = df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  reframe(
    group_share = values / sum(values),
    group_share_cumsum = cumsum(group_share),
    group_share_cumsum_round = round(group_share_cumsum, 2),
    group_share_cumsum_round_offset = replace_na(lag(group_share_cumsum_round,1),0),
    group_share_rounded_final = group_share_cumsum_round - group_share_cumsum_round_offset) %>%
  # Removing unnecessary temporary columns
  select(-group_share_cumsum, -group_share_cumsum_round, -group_share_cumsum_round_offset)
```

Doing the above will generate a tibble that looks like this:

```r
  group group_share group_share_rounded_final
  <chr>       <dbl>                     <dbl>
1 A          0.185                       0.18
2 A          0.395                       0.4 
3 A          0.252                       0.25
4 A          0.168                       0.17
5 B          0.276                       0.28
6 B          0.419                       0.42
7 B          0.210                       0.2 
8 B          0.0952                      0.1
```

Then you can verify that the new rounded values really do add up to 100%:

```r
# Verifying if the results add up to 100% within each group
rounded_totals = df_with_rounded_shares_by_group %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(total_share = sum(group_share_rounded_final))

print(rounded_totals)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# group total_share
# <chr>       <dbl>
#   1 A           1
#   2 B           1

# Yep, they all add up to 100% as expected!
```

If you look closely, though, there is a small issues: the resulting table has lost the `categories` column.

Here is the full code that fixes the issue. I admit that it's a bit of a cumbersome workaround and welcome any suggestions to improve this:

```r
df_with_rounded_shares_by_group = df %>% 
  mutate(join_col = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(
    df %>% 
      group_by(group) %>% 
      reframe(
        group_share = values / sum(values),
        group_share_cumsum = cumsum(group_share),
        group_share_cumsum_round = round(group_share_cumsum, 3),
        group_share_cumsum_round_offset = replace_na(lag(group_share_cumsum_round,1),0),
        group_share_rounded_final = group_share_cumsum_round - group_share_cumsum_round_offset) %>%
      # Removing unnecessary temporary columns
      ungroup() %>%
      select(-group,-group_share_cumsum, -group_share_cumsum_round, -group_share_cumsum_round_offset) %>%
      mutate(join_col = row_number()), 
    by='join_col') %>%
  select(-join_col)


print(df_with_rounded_shares_by_group)

>   group categories values group_share group_share_rounded_final
> 1     A       Cat1   2200   0.1848739                     0.185
> 2     A       Cat2   4700   0.3949580                     0.395
> 3     A       Cat3   3000   0.2521008                     0.252
> 4     A       Cat4   2000   0.1680672                     0.168
> 5     B       Cat1   2900   0.2761905                     0.276
> 6     B       Cat2   4400   0.4190476                     0.419
> 7     B       Cat3   2200   0.2095238                     0.210
> 8     B       Cat4   1000   0.0952381                     0.095
```

Now all of the necessary columns are in your output and the `group_share_rounded_final` column really does add up to 100%.

Btw, apologies for the ridiculously long column names. I just made them enormous to make it clear what each step was really doing.