# Voting percentage calculation error

Tags: php, math, percentage

I have created a php program where user can can vote on polls and after that, the poll result will displayed with only percentage, however I am facing an error in my program. 
 Code which I am using for percentage calculation is 
 `<?php echo round(($num_votes / $total_votes) * 100) ?>`

 Now If we talk about a sample poll result, assume we have five options 
`option A - 4 votes`
`option B - 2 votes`
`option C - 4 votes`
`option D - 1 votes`
`option E - 0 votes`
Total votes  = `11` 
In this scenario the percentage result generating is  
`option A - 36%`
`option B - 18%`
`option C - 36%`
`option D - 9%`
`option E - 0%`
But the total of percentage is `99%` instead of `100%`. What I want is total should always be `100%`
 Any help would be appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: In this case, which option should get the extra percent? A and D are both closest, but if you give it to one of them it will look as if one of them won over the other even if they got the same number of votes.

Comment: dale: ceil() will lead to percentages of 101 too ...

Comment: Yea I thought that just after I clicked add

Comment: One should be `ceil()` and all the others should be `floor()`

Comment: This might be of assistance, good advice too, though it's aimed at ruby I'm sure you can follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227215/how-to-deal-with-the-sum-of-rounded-percentage-not-being-100

Comment: "What I want is total should always be 100%" - what do you want to display if there are three candidates, three votes cast, and each candidate gets one vote each?

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with rounded numbers, you can indeed end up with...rounded numbers. And the sum of those rounded numbers will be different from the regular sum. There's little you can do to change that. If you insist, you'd have to:

1. calculate the rounded numbers
2. calculate the sum, and if not 100%,
3. loop through the rounded numbers and decide which one should get the missing percent.

But you're messing with the data. You may think you're cleaning it, but you're messing it up.

Answer (score 1):

This way lead to ~100%, 'number_format' is nice thing

```
$a = 4;
$b = 2;
$c = 4;
$d = 1;
$e = 0;
$total = $a + $b + $c + $d + $e;

$arr = array(
    'a' => number_format(($a / $total) * 100, 3),
    'b' => number_format(($b / $total) * 100, 3),
    'c' => number_format(($c / $total) * 100, 3),
    'd' => number_format(($d / $total) * 100, 3),
    'e' => number_format(($e / $total) * 100, 3)
);

foreach ($arr as $answer => $percentage) {
    echo  $answer .': '. $percentage . '<br />';
}


// this will be 100.001 so we format is
echo 'total: '. number_format(array_sum($arr), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify number of digits after decimal places in round.
ex:round(number,2);

Answer (score -2):

There's nothing out-of-the-box you can do about it, if you [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) everything you'll miss one point, if you [`ceil()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) you'll gain one point.

You *could* `floor()` everything then if then calculate the [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), if not `100` then find [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and `ceil()` it.