# What is it called when you can't have 0 and you can't have 1?

Tags: math, rounding

I am building some UI for an education app displaying user progress in percentages. Have run into an issue with rounding: 0.4 rounds down to 0, but that isn't meaningful to the user who feels they have definitely completed more than 0% of their task. Ditto for 100%: 99.5% rounds up to 100%, but obviously you're only completely done when you're completely done.

I've solved this issue in a clunky programmatic way using floor() and a special condition to round up to 1 for > 0 & < 1, so this is more of a curiosity than an urgent question, as I'm not enough of a math person to know an algorithmic solution. One might say I'm neither 100% nor 0% of a math person: I know enough to know there is probably some cute and clever name for this issue, but I don't know what it is.

It seems sort of related to "[banker's rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223778/is-bankers-rounding-really-more-numerically-stable?rq=1)" and sort of related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227215/how-to-deal-with-the-sum-of-rounded-percentage-not-being-100) [stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483430/how-to-make-rounded-percentages-add-up-to-100). But it's not exactly either of those things, I don't think?

In other words, when is something more than nothing, and when is everything not enough? If it helps at all, one time I tried to read *Gödel, Escher, Bach*, but then I read *Debt* by David Graeber instead.

Thanks! =)

Comment: This isn't related to bankers rounding. I think you just need to choose whether there's some non-zero, non-100 value that should be used for the cases that would round to these values (which I guess is what your special condition does) or alternatively you just don't apply rounding at all for values close to 0 and 100 (again you need to choose a threshold to define what "near" means in that case)

Comment: You could read [UX: What topics can I ask about here?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [UX: What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to see if your question would be better there.

Comment: @ROX yeah that is what i did! =) i'm just curious if there's a name/concept for this issue, which i'm guessing many people have run into before me?

Comment: Although not to do with rounding, more to do with including values that are close-to-but-not-including the limits, the difference between the mathematical concepts of "open intervals" and "closed intervals" is somewhat related to your aim. I have certainly encountered the requirement before, but not had a name for it.

Comment: One idea would be to round towards 50%.  You could do this by subtracting 50, round toward zero, and add 50.